# Setting style with javascript unexpected results

Tags: javascript

I am detecting browsers and trying to apply style,

```
alert(BrowserDetect.browser);
if(BrowserDetect.browser == "Opera") {
    document.getElementById(myBox).style.paddingTop = "5px";
}
```

Alert Shows the browsers name accurately but why is the style not getting applied?

Comment: When is this getting called? Is it possible the "myBox" element doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Browser-name-sniffing is almost invariably a terrible idea. What is the problem in Opera you are trying to work around with the extra padding? There is likely a simpler CSS fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an alert *inside* the `if` and see if it executes. Chances are, there's whitespace around the `Opera`string.

Comment: I alerted inside from if statement, it still alerts me but style doesn't gets applied, I have tried applying other styles too.

Comment: I doubt it. He appears to be using the QuirksMode browser detection JS (http://quirksmode.org/js/detect.html), which is pretty robust

Answer (score 1):

Put two copies of the `alert()` call inside the `if` statement, one before the style assignment and one after.  I think you'll find that the second doesn't happen, for any of several reasons:

1. The variable `myBox` doesn't exist
2. `myBox` has a value that is not an ID of a valid DOM element
3. `myBox` does name a valid element, but it is not a block type element, so padding doesn't apply

You can also try running the same code in another browser with a solid JS debugger, like Firefox + Firebug or Safari with the Develop tools enabled.  (Preferences | Advanced.)  This may lead you to the problem with that style assignment faster.

Comment: I am unable to apply styles to any other element, The id myBox exists.

Comment: That last sentence...do you mean there is an HTML element with id="myBox"?  If so, your problem is a Javascript syntax error.  You need to say getElementById('myBox') instead.  As you've written it, myBox has to be a string variable containing the ID of the element.